# Repetition of weekend's pattern after every 7 days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to repeat the **Week-Off** pattern in table2 based on given week-off frequency in table1 .

***Frequency***:  means it could be a number with multiple of 7 only like (7 , 14 , 21 ,28 so on..)

***Week-Off:*** for each employee week-off could be Nth rows.

Please find the SQL fiddle for demo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7cb68a/2

In given screenshot, If you have noticed "WhatIsGetting" field then it's working only for two week-off after that it's getting null bcz **RuleTableTemp.ShiftId** is not matching with **TempMainTable.ShiftId**.

I need a experts help on my requirement to repeat the week-off for given date range based on given ***RuleTableTemp.WeekOffFrequencyInDays***.

For now in demo I have used '7' as a hard-coded value for week-off frequency like this

```
((te.Id / 7) + 1 )
```

Please find the screen shot for more clarifications.

Feel free to ask if any information is misleading or not cleared.

**Note:** For now I have taken only example of one employee in real scenario it could be nth employees and week-off should repeat for each employee for given date range based on given week-off frequency...

***Conditions or points to remember:***

**RuleTableTemp:** for now we have two ShiftPattern for each employee but it may vary, it could be 3 or 4 patterns too.

**RuleTableTemp** Filed's name ***WeekOffFrequencyInDays*** having value '7' for EmployeeId(4536) but it can also vary for each employee and yes for eg. if there are 4 entries for "4536" employee then *WeekOffFrequencyInDays* value will be same for all.

**Example 1:**

```
if (RuleTableTemp.WeekOffFrequencyInDays == 7 )    {
       // ShiftPattern's count is 2: 
       // ShiftPattern will switch after every 7 days. 
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
if ( RuleTableTemp.WeekOffFrequencyInDays == 14) {
           // if ShiftPattern's count is 3: 
           // ShiftPattern will keep switching between 3 patterns after every 14 days 
    }
```

**Example 3:**

```
if ( RuleTableTemp.WeekOffFrequencyInDays == 21) {
           // if ShiftPattern's count is 1 means no switching is required 
    }
```

[image]

**I took almost 1 hour to explain my requirements but somebody still down-vote it instead of asking what was uncleared... so said to see this.... :(**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

This logic should match the shifts:

```
SELECT mt.* , 
       (SELECT rtt.ShiftPattern 
        FROM RuleTableTemp rtt
        WHERE rtt.EmployeeID = mt.EmployeeId AND 
              rtt.id = (((mt.seqnum - 1) % 14) / 7) + 1
        ) as Sh
FROM (SELECT mt.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mt.EmployeeId ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM TempMainTable mt
     ) mt;
```

Note that I added an explicit sequence number on the main table.  This is just to be sure that the numbers are doing what you really want (automatically generated ids can be a problem).

The key to the logic is modulo arithmetic -- taking the remainder when the sequence number of divided by 14 and then using that for matching to the week.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b66e9509d9a1392e36ddb6edf4595cc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yes it's working but why you have used % 14 and divided by 7 ?

I means will it work if I want to rotate the week-off after 21 or 28 days means any number which is divisible of 7... ?

Comment: @vijaysahu . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with more clarify on what the rows in the tables mean -- and the flexibility you need.  This answers the question that you asked here.  For instance, the `id` column in the rule table is misleading to me, because it seems like it is a "week number" column.

Comment: I have updated the query and describe it some examples... hope it will be clear now...

Comment: @vijaysahu . . . It is the question you asked, as demonstrated by the db fiddle I put together.  You can see the consequence of changing the question, which is that it attracted downvotes.  I don't play the game of "guess what I really mean".  This is a Q&A site.